# change column Value in a selection

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change a column in a selection i have made, so, selection command is

```
SELECT * FROM `HLS3011_assets_workorder`  
WHERE `date_created` >= '2016-01-01' and `date_created` < '2016-02-29'
```

I would like to change the column value of "status" from 1 to 2

Comment: Have a look at the MySQL manual for `update` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Try this :      `UPDATE  HLS3011_assets_workorder  SET status = 2 WHERE  date_created  >= '2016-01-01' AND  date_created < '2016-02-29'`

Comment: excellent stuff, worked a treat, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
UPDATE HLS3011_assets_workorder 
SET status = 2 
WHERE date_created >= '2016-01-01' AND date_created < '2016-02-29' AND status = 1
```